# How to handle with a default URL scheme

Tags: macos, cocoa, url-scheme, appkit

I want to build URI (or URL scheme) support in my app.

I do a `LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme()` in my `+ (void)initialize` and I setted the specific URL schemes also in my `info.plist`. So I have URL schemes without `Apple Script` or `Apple Events`.

When I call `myScheme:` in my favorite browser the system activates my app.

The problem is, how to handle the schemes when they are called. Or better said: How can I define what my app should do, when `myScheme:` is called.

Is there a special method that I have to implement or do I have to register one somewhere?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As you are mentioning AppleScript, I suppose you are working on Mac OS X.

A simple way to register and use a custom URL scheme is to define the scheme in your .plist:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>URLHandlerTestApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>urlHandlerTestApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

To register the scheme, put this in your AppDelegate's initialization:

```
[[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager]
    setEventHandler:self
        andSelector:@selector(handleURLEvent:withReplyEvent:)
      forEventClass:kInternetEventClass
         andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

Whenever your application gets activated via URL scheme, the defined selector gets called.

A stub for the event-handling method, that shows how to get the URL string:

```
- (void)handleURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)event
        withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)replyEvent
{
    NSString* url = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject]
                        stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
}
```

Apple's documentation: [Installing a Get URL Handler](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-SW10)

**Update**
I just noticed a problem for sandboxed apps that install the event handler in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. With enabled sandboxing, the handler method doesn't get called when the app is launched by clicking a URL that uses the custom scheme.
By installing the handler a bit earlier, in `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`, the method gets called as expected:

```
- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [[NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager]
        setEventHandler:self
            andSelector:@selector(handleURLEvent:withReplyEvent:)
          forEventClass:kInternetEventClass
             andEventID:kAEGetURL];
}

- (void)handleURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)event
        withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)replyEvent
{
    NSString* url = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject]
                        stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
}
```

---

On the iPhone, the easiest way to handle URL-scheme activation is, to implement UIApplicationDelegate's `application:handleOpenURL:` - [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleOpenURL:)

Comment: Stupid question, but where exactly is the AppDelegate's intialization? Which method?

Comment: What is keyDirectObject and where is it defined?  I don't understand what the value of keyDirectObject is supposed to be.  Thanks.

Comment: For those that are wondering like me, "How does keyDirectObject compile without syntax error for a missing symbol?", it's defined in AE/AppleEvents.h as an enum case.  Somehow AE/AppleEvents.h gets included in your app even if you don't directly include it.

Comment: If you're targeting macOS 10.13 and up you can use the new NSApplicationDelegate method `func application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL])` -- no need to register with NSAppleEventManager, just implement the method in your app delegate.

Comment: How to register my application to be used for my custom URLs? LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme returns -54 which I translate into "Sandbox says no" (https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-54)".

Comment: I can confirm that your solution works even today in macOS Monterey 12.6.1.

Answer (score 9):

All credits should go to **weichsel** and **kch**

I'm just adding swift(2.2/3.0) code for your convenience

```swift
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    NSAppleEventManager.shared().setEventHandler(self, andSelector: #selector(self.handleGetURL(event:reply:)), forEventClass: UInt32(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: UInt32(kAEGetURL) )
}

@objc func handleGetURL(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor, reply:NSAppleEventDescriptor) {
    if let urlString = event.paramDescriptor(forKeyword: keyDirectObject)?.stringValue {
        print("got urlString \(urlString)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to avoid the application to be activated and sent to the foreground when receiving an URL?

Answer (score 6):

> The problem is, how to handle the schemes when they are called.

That's where the Apple Events come in. When Launch Services wants your app to open a URL, it sends your app a `kInternetEventClass`/`kAEGetURL` event.

[The Cocoa Scripting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications) uses [this very task as an example of installing an event handler](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-BBCIDFHG).

Answer (score 4):

I'm just adding slightly different Swift 4/5 version of the code:

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    NSAppleEventManager
        .shared()
        .setEventHandler(
            self,
            andSelector: #selector(handleURL(event:reply:)),
            forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass),
            andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL)
        )

}

@objc func handleURL(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor, reply: NSAppleEventDescriptor) {
    if let path = event.paramDescriptor(forKeyword: keyDirectObject)?.stringValue?.removingPercentEncoding {
        NSLog("Opened URL: \(path)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to avoid the application to be activated and sent to the foreground when receiving an URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the “get URL” command in a scripting terminology SDEF and implement the corresponding method. For example, Terminal’s SDEF contains the following command definition for handling URLs

```
<command name="get URL" code="GURLGURL" description="Open a command an ssh, telnet, or x-man-page URL." hidden="yes">
    <direct-parameter type="text" description="The URL to open." />
</command>
```

and declares that the application responds to it:

```
<class name="application" code="capp" description="The application's top-level scripting object.">
    <cocoa class="TTApplication"/>
    <responds-to command="get URL">
        <cocoa method="handleGetURLScriptCommand:" />
    </responds-to>
</class>
```

The TTApplication class (a subclass of NSApplication) defines the method:

```
- (void)handleGetURLScriptCommand:(NSScriptCommand *)command { … }
```