# NSApplicationDelegate application active because of URL Protocol

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Hey!  I have my Mac application set up to launch on myApp:// protocol is called in a browser, like Safari, but I cannot seem to be able to do an action when the application is called by that protocol.  The delegate method would have to be something like:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActiveByURL:(NSURL *)protocol;
```

I don't know this because I am new at Mac developing, but I am somewhat good at iPhone developing, so I know the iPhone development way, but not the Mac development way

Comment: What does the documentation for NSApplicationDelegate say?

Comment: I checked the documentation and I actually found absolutely nothing this time.  I went through every NSApplicationDelegate and NSApplication function looking for anything that looks like it'd work and didn't find anything.  I know it's possible, because iTunes and Mail do it.

Comment: and this was a dupilcate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991072/how-to-handle-with-a-default-url-scheme

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `NSAppleEventManager`. You know, AppKit predates Internet, OS X still works mainly on files not on URL schemes, etc. UIKit is sometimes better. Read this [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-SW3).

In practice:  First, register a handler in `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`

```
-(void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    [appleEventManager setEventHandler:self 
                           andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:)
                         forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
}
```

and then implement the handler

```
- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString *urlAsString = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    ... do something ... 
}
```

You also need to register your scheme in `Info.plist`.