# Cannot send NSDistributedNotification's from SIMBL plugin

Tags: objective-c, macos, plugins, osx-lion, simbl

I am developing an SIMBL plugin for TextEdit, the plugin adds an additional menu. The menu has a number of items that when selected (among other things) send messages to my own application. To do this I have been using NSDistributedNotificationCenter however I am unable to send notifications from my bundle within TextEdit.

I have checked the code I am using in a separate application and it seems to work so I do not understand why my bundle in TextEdit is not able to send messages.

The post notification code:

```
NSDictionary *user = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"TextEdit", @"applicationName", 
                      @"289", @"applicationVersion", 
                      @"1", @"menuItem", nil];
NSString *observedObject = @"com.drake.DDX";
NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[center postNotificationName:@"DDXNotification" object:observedObject userInfo:user     deliverImmediately:YES];
```

And the code in the receiver:

```
NSString *observedObject = @"com.drake.DDX";
    NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"DDXNotification" object:observedObject];
```

This code seems to work if I add it to another one of my applications so it makes me think something is going on in TextEdit or SIMBL that I am not aware of.

I have checked that the menu items are executing the method properly by showing an NSAlert in TextEdit as soon as the method is executed.

Any help is appreciated.

(Edit) I have found out that when I post a notification if the userInfo dictionary is nil the notification is received by my application so it appears there is a problem with the NSDictionary I am sending or the receiver method signature.

Comment: You have correctly identified the problem.  Under sandboxing you can't pass a userInfo payload with your notification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your NSDistributedNotificationCenter isn't working.  However I think I can give you a different way to skin this cat.

Design a URL scheme along the lines of myapp://menu/menu_item?arguments.

The important bit is the myapp scheme.

Follow the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991072/how-to-handle-with-a-default-url-scheme) to register your app as the default handler of this scheme.

Now in response to a menu selection compose an appropriate URL using myapp as the scheme and call

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://menu/menu_item"];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]openURL:url];
```