# Custom URL Types on Mac Objective-C

Tags: xcode, macos, url, hyperlink

How can I create custom URL types that I can perform an action with the data passed into the app.
I've tried this with no luck:

```
- (void)handleURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)replyEvent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify one or more keys for the CFBundleURLTypes dictionary in your app's property list file (or in XCode target editor).

Then in your app delegate `applicationWillFinishLaunching` write something like

```
NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
[appleEventManager setEventHandler:self andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:) forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
```

Comment: Seems you still have to implement your handler method :)

Comment: Ok it works now. but how can I make it so that if the URL is myapp://foo that it will preform an action and if it is myapp://bar it will preform a different action.

Comment: @mifki Do you know if this would work on a sandboxed app?  I understood that Apple Events were severely limited in a sandboxed environment.

Comment: It will work. From documentation: "With App Sandbox, you can receive Apple events and respond to Apple events, but you cannot send Apple events to arbitrary apps. By using a temporary exception entitlement, you can enable the sending of Apple events to a list of specific apps that you specify, as described in Entitlement Key Reference."

Comment: A more complete answer to this question including an example of the handler method is described here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991072/how-to-handle-with-a-default-url-scheme

    - (void)handleURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)event
        withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)replyEvent
{
    NSString* url = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject]
                        stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
}

Answer (score 2):

1. Select your **project** in the left pane.
2. Select your **target** in the list.
3. Go to the **Info** tab.
4. Add new URLs under **URL Types**.

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping get on the right track. I just need to know how to preform an action when the URL is opened.