# Custom Actions for Custom URL Schemes Mac Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, url-scheme

how can I make it so that if the URL is myapp://foo that it will preform an action and if it is myapp://bar it will preform a different action.
I've gotten this far with my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567028/custom-url-types-on-mac-objective-c)
Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your URL scheme registered inside your application, you should be able to capture the URL used to open your application with something like this

```
- (void)handleURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor*)replyEvent {
    NSString *calledURL = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"%@", calledURL);
    // Split and do something with calledURL
}
```

Once you have that URL you should easily be able to split it and determine what you want to do.

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991072/how-to-handle-with-a-default-url-scheme) on exactly this as well.