# Launch a desktop application from a browser

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm trying to find a way to launch a desktop application from a browser for os x. This application will be for customers only and should only be used for the hardware we provide.

I'd like to start off by saying I think this is a stupid idea. I'm being forced to use this approach by our CEO. I understand security policies could be an issue, as well as glaring vulnerabilities.

Since they can only run this on a single device I don't know that jws would be the right solution. I haven't used it but based on what I've read it doubles as a distribution method (which we don't want). If it were to be jws then it would have to some how have to recognize the device we provided them to ensure it is being placed on the appropriate hardware, possibly based on the serial # (which I don't believe you can get from the browser).

Additionally, the browser would call methods and pass arguments to the application.

Is this even possible? If so, what tool would you recommend? Again, I'm only the messenger for this terrible idea.

Comment: Run. Run away as fast you can. Sound like your CEO doesn't know the first thing about technology and should hire a CTO.

Comment: @ndrone lol we have a CTO that he isn't apsdoifjapsdof listening to but we're *hopefully* getting a new CEO in the near future.

Comment: Yeah, the closest thing I can think of is an Applet, but it won't work. Not really much opportunity for you here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have Chrome or Safari configured to handle `http://<uri>` URIs, but many other types exist. Have you ever seen custom URI schemes used like `itunes://<uri>`, `steam://<uri>`, or `skype://<uri>` ?

Just like for `http`, when your OS tries to fetch the resource, it will attempt to handle the request in the application that registered a handler for that scheme.

If that's the kind of thing you're looking for, [this question has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991072/how-to-handle-with-a-default-url-scheme).

My suspicion is that you were unaware of the term. If that answer works for you, we can mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Would you be able to interact with the app from the browser as well?

Comment: That's what I figured, I don't even believe what he is asking for is possible and it shouldn't be.

Comment: This is part of your job no one told you about. You have to convince ignorant people that their "good" ideas are rubbish. Best of luck to you, mate.

Comment: Haha thanks, an I'll accept yours after a day because I'd be willing to bet money Apple would never allow the level of access he is wanting. Not even MS would pull that garbage.

Comment: Don't sweat it. This isn't really an answer to your question. If you don't get the answer you're looking for, I would probably just delete the question. As I'm sure we agree, it's probably best people aren't even thinking about such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to @naomik's answer (which I believe is the right one), there are projects like [AppJS](http://appjs.com/), [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/developer/) or [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) which are pretty much willing to bring web based apps to the desktop.

For the matter of communicating the App and your browser (should I say your server?), you could use an approach of message queues and websockets to get there, surely, it is a huge effort of orchestration and workarounds but in the end it is possible to get you there.

Comment: Electron is what I'm really pushing for, hopefully seeing this feedback he will re-evaluate his position.

Comment: Godspeed! It will be a PITA yet sounds terribly interesting for a project

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

This does not appear to be possible. If you are considering this please don't, there are better solutions. I have finally convinced my CEO to use Angular2 inside electron for example.